# Swift app crashes when mapping through a "large" array in UI View

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, memory

I have a View where I generate an array of strings and map through them to render them as a joined piece of text (like a paragraph).

When the array has < 980 or so elements, this works fine. But when the array is bigger than this, the entire app crashes and throws `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x16b307fd8)` by @main at the top level of my app.

Here is the code:

`

```
struct ParagraphView: View {
    var strings = Array(repeating: "Hello, world", count: 1000)
    
    var body: some View {
        strings.map { string in
            return Text(string)
                .foregroundColor(.blue)
        }.reduce(Text(""), +).fontWeight(.medium).multilineTextAlignment(.leading).padding(30.0).textSelection(.enabled)
    }
}
```

`

From what I can understand, the EXC_BAD_ACCESS error is saying that I am trying to access a piece of memory that has been deallocated.

I have both Address Sanitizer and Zombie objects turned on, but they are not throwing any errors/warnings.

I guess I could "batch" the array into a group of smaller arrays and render them all, but this is jank and I want to understand what is going on.

Comment: This kind of work should not be done in a `body` they get reloaded many times at the discretion of SwiftUI

Comment: As lorem ipsum said, you should not be performing this work in the view. Also, you should concatenate the strings into a single string and render a single `Text` view instead of many text views

Comment: Good call, did it this way because we need to dynamically format portions of the paragraph but this is better done through AttributedString